# How to use a variable in an array?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm using PASCAL for a course i'm doing and i'm having trouble with an assignment, in my program i'm using 2 arrays that uses a variable from a user's input but when i go to run the program it comes up with, Error: Can't evaluate constant expression. The code for the array is:

```
Var
        x : integer;
        s : array[1..x] of real;
        n : array[1..x] of string[30];
```

Here x is the user's input, is there a way for an array to go from 1 to x?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `;`?

Comment: yeah that's just a typo on my behalf, i'm not missing any ; in my program

Comment: You need a dynamic array

Comment: Please state the exact compiler and version the next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `x` is a variable, that won't work indeed. The range of a so called *static array* must be a *constant expression*, i.e. it must be known at compile time.

So what you want won't work, as is.

In FreePascal, you can use [dynamic arrays](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array), though. Their lengths can be set and changed at runtime.

```
var
  x: Integer;
  s: array of Real;
  n: array of string[30]; // why not just string?
```

and later:

```
  x := someUserInput(); // pseudo code!
  SetLength(s, x);
  SetLength(n, x);
```

You should be aware of the fact that dynamic arrays are `0`-based, so your indexes run from `0` up to `x - 1`. But for the limits of the array, you should rather use [`Low()`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/low.html) and [`High()`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/high.html) instead:

```
  for q := Low(s) to High(s) do
    // access s[q];
```

*(`Low()` and `High()` are not the topic, but just know they can also be used for static arrays, and that they return the actual array bounds -- I always use High and Low for this)*

Comment: Thank you! I have seemed to run into more problems which i assume has to do with the array, It says Error: Operator is not overloaded: "Dynamic Array of SmallInt" div "SmallInt", "Dyanmic Array of SmallInt" mod "ShortInt". I've put my entire program in the OP.

Comment: Vampiric activity detected

Comment: @David: yes, indeed.

Comment: @LeCarloVC: if you have more problems, you are free to post them as new questions.Shifting your goalposts is not well regarded in sports, and neither is it here.

Comment: @LeCarloVC: I see quite a few problems with your code. You can probably see them too, if you properly format the code. Do not mix different styles for keywords and work on your indentation. And `a - b` is subtraction.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I made another question with more detail on it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is not so simple as using managed types like dynamic arrays suggested by @RudyVelthuis but more funny solution providing some comprehension
about how it works internally :)

```
program dynarr;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

type
    TArrayReal = array[1..High(Integer)] of Real;
    TArrayString30 = array[1..High(Integer)] of string[30];
    PArrayReal = ^TArrayReal;
    PArrayString30 = ^TArrayString30;
var
    i: Integer;
    x: Integer;
    s: PArrayReal;
    n: PArrayString30;
begin
    Write('Count: '); Readln(x);
    // Allocate memory for the actual count of the elements
    s := GetMem(SizeOf(Real) * x);
    n := GetMem(SizeOf(string[30]) * x);
    try
        for i := 1 to x do
        begin
            Write('Row ', i:3, ': '); Readln(s^[i], n^[i]);
        end;
        Writeln('Your input was:');
        for i := 1 to x do
            Writeln('Row ', i:3, ': ', s^[i]:10:3, n^[i]: 20);
    finally
        // Do not forget to release allocated memory
        FreeMem(s);
        FreeMem(n);
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Yeah, much more "fun" than a simple dynamic array.

Comment: This is simply abysmal advice

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What you do not understand in my introduction to the code?

Comment: Why stop there. Why not write the whole thing in asm. This is shockingly bad advice. Hence my vote. You state that it is a joke answer. What response would you expect?

Comment: But hey you got a sympathy up vote so it just goes to show that the pascal community's love for poor quality continues. Better to reward someone for trying not matter how poor the attempt is than to attempt to promote quality.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My answer is half-joke but also for educational purposes. Luck of basic knowledge (up to assembler) leads to "Vampiric activity" :)